# Cursor Based Record vs Strong ref cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I'm new in Oracle databases and pl/sql language. My question is what's the differences between strong ref cursor and cursor based record - like e.g. "var_exmpl" variable which will store cursor values i.e. "cur_exmpl%rowtype"

Answer (score 1):

You use ref cursor types to declare cursor variables. You can then fetch from those cursor variables as you would an explicit cursor. In both cases, you can and usually will fetch into a record.

With an explicit cursor, you can declare the record based on the cursor. With a strong ref cursor type, I would declare a record based on the same type used to declare the ref cursor.

Here are some examples:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE employee_rt IS RECORD
   (
      employee_id   employees.employee_id%TYPE,
      salary        employees.salary%TYPE
   );

   TYPE strong_rc IS REF CURSOR
      RETURN employee_rt;

   strong_rec              employee_rt;

   CURSOR twocols_cur
   IS
      SELECT employee_id, salary FROM employees;

   rec_from_explicit_cur   twocols_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN strong_rc FOR SELECT employee_id, salary FROM employees;

   FETCH strong_rc INTO strong_rec;

   CLOSE strong_rc;

   OPEN twocols_cur;

   FETCH twocols_cur INTO rec_from_explicit_cur;

   CLOSE twocols_cur;
END;
/
```

Comment: So in both cases we get the same result using different cursors. There is no difference between them so which one is better for performance?

Comment: No difference performance wise. Generally you use a cursor variable when you need to (a) change which query you are going to execute at runtime - you can OPEN FOR a dynamic query (string) or different static queries with case or If, or (b) you need to pass the cursor variable to another block or out to a non-PL/SQL context, like a Java program.